# Is there a name for a distribution which is exponential in a power of $x$?

Tags: probability

Is there a name for the distribution
$$
f(x|\lambda,\beta) = \frac{\beta\,\lambda^{1/\beta}}{\Gamma(1/\beta)} \exp\left(-\lambda x^{\beta}\right)
$$
for $x\in[0,\infty)$?

Answer (score 0):

Yep, is a generalized Gamma distribution. With $d=1, a= 1/\lambda^{\beta}, p=\beta$. Chek

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_gamma_distribution